# Movable Type: Specify only one keyword from MTEntryKeywords

Tags: movabletype

I have several keywords (1~3 words) stored in `<MTEntryKeywords>` field separated by commas.
I want to take out the first keyword from MTEntryKeywords.

Example 1:

In the Keywords field I have entered: gadgets,phone,apple,

Want to display: gadgets

Example 2:

In the Keywords field I have entered: food,coffee,apple,

Want to display: food

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but something like this should do the trick (assuming you're using a recent enough version of MT)

```
<mt:entrykeywords regex_replace="/^([^,]+)(,.*)?$/","$1">
```

Basically, the regular expression there is saying "keep only everything up to, but not including, the first comma".